# User Docker Hub registry containers in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

Is there any way to load containers stored in docker hub registry in Amazon Sagemaker.
According to some documentation, it should be possible, but I have not been able to find any relevan example or guide for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use any registry when working with Docker on a SageMaker notebook, as of this writing other SageMaker components presently only support images from Amazon ECR repositories.